# How do I change the string element of vector to json in Rust?

Tags: json, vector, rust, redis

```
["{\"from\":1,\"date\":1651619967}", 
"{\"from\":1,\"date\":1651619961}"]
```

I have this type of vector. I want to print out the string elements in this vector in the form of Json.

```
[{
"from":1,
"date":1651619967
}
, {
"from":1,
"date":1651619967
}]
```

I want to change it to a beautiful Json form like the one above. How can I do this? The only answer is to use the for statement? I want to know how to do this efficiently.

```
    let values:Vec<String> = redis_conn
        .zrevrange(room_key, 0, -1)
        .expect("failed to execute ZREVRANGE for 'room_key'");
```

For your information, the vector above is the result obtained through zrevrange from redis.

Comment: To be clear, you want to convert from string to (pretty) string, right? Also btw, don't worry too much about efficiency because the serialization/deserialization will be the heavier stuff--any object copying or creation in the code you write will be relatively simple and fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input you have is a rust vec, containing JSON encoded strings, and if I understand the question correctly, you would like to obtain a pretty-printed version of the whole thing (including the containing vec).

One way is to use `serde_json` to parse the strings, then it's `to_string_pretty` method to obtain the pretty printed string:

```
use serde_json::{self, Value};

fn main() {
    let input = vec![
        "{\"from\":1,\"date\":1651619967}", 
        "{\"from\":1,\"date\":1651619961}"
    ];

    // Convert input into Vec<Value>, by parsing each string
    let elems = input.into_iter()
        .map(serde_json::from_str)
        .collect::<Result<Vec<Value>,_>>()
        .unwrap();
    
    let json_val = Value::Array(elems);

    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string_pretty(&json_val).unwrap());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=efa9fe6ad89f1eb4e86f7b93950ee960)

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "date": 1651619967,
    "from": 1
  },
  {
    "date": 1651619961,
    "from": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot. I wish you good luck on that day

Comment: You're welcome @hyerimchoi! Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the tick if it answers your question.